# Huge number of neurons in the hidden layer yields better result, why?

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Can you please explain why increasing the number of neurons in a hidden layer by 20x (1000 neurons) gives me better results (about 9% on the testing dataset) compared to only 34 neurons?

Training shape: (8589, 5, 11) (75% of dataset), testing on 2858 samples (25% of dataset)

My architecture is as follows:

```
Bidirectional LSTM of size 50 neurons
Dense of size 1000 neurons (activation=sigmoid)
Dense of size 1 neuron (activation=sigmoid)
```

I got worse results with this one (which should be theoretically correct according to book):

```
Bidirectional LSTM of size 50 neurons
Dense of size 34 neurons (activation=sigmoid)
Dense of size 1 neuron (activation=sigmoid)
```

Comment: Is it repeatable? Otherwise: luck

Comment: @ThomasWeller I get the same result when I run it again.

Comment: What kind of an explanation do you seek? And why you think that one is needed? Why the 2nd architecture you show should be "theoretically" better (in a field that is infamous for its lack of solid theoretical foundations)? According to which book?

Comment: @desertnaut 
I figured it out guys. Thanks for commenting. The problem is that I am decreasing the number of neurons from 50 to 34 === underfitting. Underfitting occurs when there are too few neurons in the hidden layers to adequately detect the signals in a complicated data set.

BTW the book ;) "Artificial Intelligence for Humans, Volume 3: Deep Learning and Neural Networks" ISBN: 1505714346

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing the number of neurons from 50 (input layer) to 34 (hidden layer) results in underfitting.

> Underfitting occurs when there are too few neurons in the hidden layers to adequately detect the signals in a complicated data set.

There is a great article on this topic https://www.heatonresearch.com/2017/06/01/hidden-layers.html

I would also like to recommend this book for further reading "Artificial Intelligence for Humans, Volume 3: Deep Learning and Neural Networks" ISBN: 1505714346